# Why does JavaScript let you store an array and a function in one variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

I came across this by mistake one day while programming a game:

```
var foo = function() { alert("Hello, World!"); }

foo[0] = "Zero";
foo[1] = "One";
foo[2] = "Two";
foo[3] = "Three";

foo(); // Alerts "Hello, World!"
alert(foo[2]); // Alerts "Two"
```

Why does JavaScript let you do this? Is this a glitch?

Comment: Your question implies you feel that this is a problem of some kind: may I ask *why*, because my first response to your question is, basically, *why not*?

Comment: Perhaps because you don't call the same properties or methods on a function as you do on an array?

Comment: Functions are objects. Objects can have properties, so `foo.bar = "baz"` is legal. Javascript has two methods of accessing properties on objects: dot-notation and bracket-notation. You're using the latter.

Comment: @DavidThomas It's not a problem. I was just wondering if this is normal JavaScript behavior. It could actually be quite useful.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Oh, I see now.

Comment: Welcome to the rabbit hole.

Comment: @LucTheRedstoner It is quite useful. Look at jQuery. You can call the jQuery function like `jQuery("selector")`, yet it has properties/methods like `jQuery.each` and whatnot

Comment: Nice question by the way, never noticed that (of adding properties to a function).

Comment: As others stated, functions are objects. Keep this in mind when it comes time to start passing callback functions around. Also keep in mind that when you do that, the function keeps its original variable scope.

Comment: @LucTheRedstoner: *"It could actually be quite useful."* Oh, it's *very* useful. :-)

Comment: It might help if someone can provide a link to more information about this kind of weak typing (I believe this is also the case in Lua).

Comment: There is no "why". There is only JavaScript.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are no arrays here. For example, `Array.isArray(foo)` is false.

Instead, you are giving `foo` four properties, named `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"` [1], with different values. This is completely valid, because functions are objects; you can always attach properties, with whatever name you like, to objects.

You could also do:

```
foo.otherProp = "hi!";

alert(foo.otherProp);
```

---

[1]: Note that property names are always converted to strings before setting them; doing `foo[{ toString: function () { return "baz"; }] = 5` will be the same as `foo["baz"] = 5` or `foo.baz = 5`. Similarly, doing `foo[0] = "whatever"` is the same as doing `foo["0"] = "whatever"`.

Comment: JS is converting the `0` on `foo[0]` to `"0"` *(string)* so `foo[0]` and `foo["0"]` are the same, right Domenic? Tested here on console and seems like that.

Comment: Yeah, I added a footnote about that.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL: Correct.

Comment: *"There are no arrays here."* Perfect way to open an answer on this. Just perfect.

Comment: Additional info when debugging: Using `console.log` on `foo` only returns the `function()`. For the complete info about `foo`, use `console.dir` and the properties will be shown.

Comment: These are not the arrays your looking for (hand wave)

Comment: This is why I hate JavaScript.

Answer (score 9):

> Why does JavaScript let you store an array and a function in one variable?

It doesn't. It lets you store a reference to a function in a variable. Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript, and so they can have properties, including ones with names like `"0"`, `"1"`, etc.

You're seeing a couple of things at play here:

1. What I said above, functions are objects, and so you can add properties to them.
2. You can add properties ad-hoc, there's no need to predefine them as in some other languages.
3. In JavaScript, you can refer to a property using dot notation and a literal (`foo.bar)`, or using bracketed notation and a string (`foo["bar"]`).
4. When you use bracketed notation, the thing within the brackets is cast to a string if it isn't already one, so `[0]` is actually `["0"]`.

And yes, that last is true even when you're dealing with arrays, because standard [arrays in JavaScript aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html). (There are recent additions, `Int32Array` and such, which are true arrays, but `Array` is not.)

Comment: Removed sentence talking about storing references to an array in a variable, since that seemed confusing and potentially misleading. Feeling a bit bad now, probably should have just commented and let you do it yourself, sorry.

Comment: @Domenic: Thanks, but it was just a typo ("array" where I meant "function").

Comment: This gives a nice separation of all the different things going on in this piece of code. +1

Answer (score 4):

The answer is quite simple, and can be expressed as a syllogism (for my amusement).

All objects can have developer-defined properties<sup>1</sup>.
All functions are objects.
Therefore, all functions can have developer-defined properties.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically not *all* objects.  "Hardened" objects cannot be mutated by untrusted code, and objects provided by the application embedding the JavaScript runtime can customize their behavior to prevent this.  These are edge cases, though.  Un-hardened objects created from within the JavaScript runtime should all exhibit this functionality, and most of the time these are the objects one is trying to mutate.

Answer (score 3):

`foo[0]` in this case assigns the value to a property named "0".  A function is an object and can have properties added to it.

In the same way, these two are equivilant:

```
foo["abc"]
foo.abc
```

Answer (score 1):

What no one's mentioned so far is that this feature allows you to associate information with a function that might be useful to the function, but without polluting the global space with a lot of public data that might create collisions and so on.

This is of course a feature of OOP/prototyping in general, but it has the added benefit of letting you call a function directly, and not as a property of a more general object.

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything (including functions) in Javascript is an object, so you can give it extra properties like `0` and `1`.

Comment: This is not true: `5` is not an object. Try: `5.foo = "bar"; alert(5.foo);`. The same goes for all other primitives. The general test if something is an object is whether `Object(thing) === thing`.

Comment: @Domenic: True, but in fact, the primitive is promoted to an object (or would be if syntax were handled, e.g. `(5).foo = "bar"`; without the `()` the `.` looks like a decimal point), a property is added to it, and then that object is thrown away. (This is the whole reason `"string".anyMethodHere()` works.) The statement *is* too broad, but not by much. :-)

Comment: @Domenic In addition to what @T.J.Crowder said, you can also do `5..foo = 'bar';`. The first dot is interpreted as a decimal point and the second one is interpreted as property access

Comment: Yes; none of this changes what I said in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question has nothing to do with your title.

The answer to the question asked in your title, "Why does JavaScript let you store an array and a function in one variable?", JavaScript is a *dynamically typed* language, and that means you can put whatever you like in a variable, and the interpreter won't complain.

In the body of your question, you wonder why you are allowed to set attributes of a function, as if it were an object or an array.

Well, you just can.  That's the definition of the language.  It's enormously useful to be able to add metainformation about a function.

But yes, JavaScript is covered with sharp edges and pointy bits, so you have to be careful.

Comment: `First of all, your question has nothing to do with your title.` - while that's true to us, it's obviously not apparent to the OP, as they thought they were treating the function as an array (because of setting numeric properties). JavaScript being dynamically typed has nothing to do with the OP's title - they're obviously referring to incorrectly thinking the variable is holding both a function and an array. And `Well, you just can. That's the definition of the language.` isn't a helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions are first class *objects*.

```
function foo() {}
var isObject = foo instanceof Object;
// isObject is true
```

That's the deal with assigning functions to a variable, passing them as arguments, returning them from functions etc.

*[Reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)*